# Is there a variable with a list of languages supported by Org-mode src-blocks?

Tags: elisp, org-babel

In org-mode, is there a variable/const/whatever containing a list of all  languages supported in "BEGIN/END_SRC" blocks?

Are there any other methods to list them? (except parsing a list of ob-*.el files)

Comment: For languages with syntax highlighting support, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22484646/113848).

Comment: What do you mean by "supported"? Do you want them to be eval-able? Mere fontification doesn't even require an `ob-*.el` file.

Comment: For languages that can be executed, see http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `org-babel-load-languages` lists all the languages that can currently be evaluated in a org-mode buffer.  The default is just `emacs-lisp`.  More may (will) be available but won't be evaluatable by default.

You still get syntax highlighting of other languages as long as the corresponding major mode is installed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limitation.

```
org-src-lang-modes is a variable defined in `org-src.el'.
Its value is shown below.

Documentation:
Alist mapping languages to their major mode.
The key is the language name, the value is the string that should
be inserted as the name of the major mode.  For many languages this is
simple, but for language where this is not the case, this variable
provides a way to simplify things on the user side.
For example, there is no ocaml-mode in Emacs, but the mode to use is
`tuareg-mode'.

You can customize this variable.

Value: (("ocaml" . tuareg)
 ("elisp" . emacs-lisp)
 ("ditaa" . artist)
 ("asymptote" . asy)
 ("dot" . fundamental)
 ("sqlite" . sql)
 ("calc" . fundamental)
 ("C" . c)
 ("cpp" . c++)
 ("C++" . c++)
 ("screen" . shell-script))
```

If there is no built in support, `org-mode` will try to find a mode named after whatever you named the source block. That is, if you have a source block such as:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC whatever-language-you-want

#+END_SRC
```

And you press `C-c '` inside it, you'll see the echo `No such language mode: whatever-language-you-want-mode`.

For Babel evaluation support, see: http://orgmode.org/manual/Languages.html#Languages

Comment: "you'll see the echo No such language mode: whatever-language-you-want-mode"... except if you have `whatever-language-you-want-mode` installed. Also, you should probably make it clear that this variable is not the one the OP is looking for, but instead the answer is "all languages for which there is a mode defined".